# Как строку сделать массивом? (javascript и jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как строку сделать массивом?
Нам нужен массив вида:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2013',  1000,      400],
          ['2014',  1170,      460],
          ['2015',  660,       1120],
          ['2016',  1030,      540],
          ['2016',  1030,      540]
        ]);
```

ИЗ HTML мы соберем переменную:

```
chart2 = chart2 +'['+'\''+ $(this).find(".row-z").attr('order')+'\''+',' + $(this).find(".statistics-profit").text()+',' + $(this).find(".income").text() +','+$(this).find(".profit").text()+','+$(this).find(".rez-sum").text() +'],' ;
```

Отображается она верно, но получается, что она является строкой, а не массивом, т.е. при передачи её в функцию:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart2 );
```

Выходит сообщение, что это не массив
Подскажите как идентифицировать массив, ведь в текстовом виде он выглядит верно, может быть есть какой нибудь парсер?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае наверно имеет смысл сразу формировать массив, а не клеить все в одну строку.

```
 var chart2 = [];
 var columns = ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'];
 chart2.push(columns);

 var values = [....];
 chart2.push(columns);
```

Думаю идея понятна.

А по существу вопроса - я думаю что может помочь функция `eval`. Только учтите, что в вашем случае это одевание брюк через голову. Да и сильно небезопасно оно.